# React native push data to another screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to push and get data from one screen to another. I have two screen right now, ProductListing & ProductDetail and a list of dummy entries. On my ProductListing screen, I did the following:

```
pushProductDetailScreen(item){

  this.props.navigator.push({
    screen: 'ProductDetail',
    title: item.name,
    subtitle: item.type,
    backButtonTitle: '',
    data: item
  });
 };

  <FlatList
        data={S_Entries}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            roundAvatar
            title={item.name}
            subtitle={item.type}
            avatar={{ uri: item.image }}
            containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
            button onPress={() => {this.pushProductDetailScreen(item)}}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
```

On my ProductDetail screen, I would like to received my array of item and have no idea how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `passProps`

[example](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=pushparams)

ProductListing.js

```
  this.props.navigator.push({
    screen: 'ProductDetail',
    title: item.name,
    subtitle: item.type,
    backButtonTitle: '', 
    passProps: {   
       data: item
    },
  });
```

ProductDetail.js

```
var data = this.props.data;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you